# Trying to add a struct to an array of struct (golang)

Tags: arrays, go, struct

The requirement is to add an "instance" of a struct from a function to be added to an array of struct in the main. I tried using "append" but it won't work on an array. I tried using slice method (append) and also pointers but it just made my code worst. I should be able to access all the elements in the array of three fruits (of structs) for output. Thanks!

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Fruit struct {
    name   string
    color  string
    weight float32
}

func newFruit(name string) (string, string, float32) {
    return name, "unk", 0
}

func main() {
    var basket [3]Fruit 
    var name string

    for i := 0; i < len(basket); i++ {
        fmt.Print("Enter name: ")
        fmt.Scanln(&name)
        basket[i] := newFruit(name) //<-- error: assignment mismatch, tried "=" but still not working
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(basket); i++ {
        fmt.Println("Name: ", i, ": ", basket[i].name)
        fmt.Println("Color: ", i, ": ", basket[i].color)
        fmt.Println("Weight: ", i, ": ", basket[i].weight)
    }
}
```

Comment: newFruit doesnt return Fruit

Comment: You cannot use `:=` when assigning to an index expression, use `=` instead. The `newFruit` function returns 3 separate values, it does not return a single struct, so there's an immediate mismatch in `basket[i] = newFruit(name)`, in other words, `basket[i]` represents one composite value, not three separate primitives, i.e. you cannot assign 3 primitives to a single composite with a plain `x = y` expression. To make it work you'd have to do `basket[i].name, basket[i].color, basket[i].weight = newFruit(name)`.

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignment_statements *"An assignment statement may assign a single value to a single variable, or multiple values **to a matching number** of variables."* That means that if the RHS of the assignment is a list of 3 values then the LHS of the assignment MUST be a list of 3 variables.

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva for the background information.

Answer (score 2):

Your `newFruit` needs to return a `Fruit` rather than two strings and a float32.

For example:

```
func newFruit(name string) Fruit {
    return Fruit{name: name, color: "unk", weight: 0}
}
```

As @mkopriva points out in the comments, you also have a typo:

```
basket[i] := newFruit(name)  // WRONG
```

should be

```
basket[i] = newFruit(name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been staring at this for the last three days. I tried the example in https://gobyexample.com/structs and I couldn't make it work. I also thought that returning three values from the function will line up when trying to assign it to the array in main (sadly mistaken). Thank you again.

Comment: lol when I say staring, I didn't mean just staring at my screen. I read through the documentation, checked beginner websites: GeekforGeeks, etc, googled all over Stackoverflow, read through class notes, etc.

Comment: @JaySanti please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if you found it helpful, so that the question may be marked as resolved. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers